# how to run nAudio on Windows XP?

Tags: c#, wpf, naudio

I am using [nAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) on my WPF Application.
I have followed their tutorial on [How to play mp3](http://naudio.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=MP3) And everything works fine.

However, in their tutorial they mention :

> 3) In a method – that only needs to be called once, setup the
>   waveOutDevice. In this example we will use WASPI – which is available
>   on Vista and Windows 7.  A more detailed discussion on which output
>   device to chose and when, to come latter
>
> waveOutDevice = new WasapiOut(AudioClientShareMode.Shared, 100);

And for some reason, they didn't discuss on how to do that.
Anyone has a clue? 
And if you do know which output device i should use, do i need to check which OS
the user has and set output device accordingly or the one for XP will work on

Comment: [How do i choose an output driver](http://mark-dot-net.blogspot.com/2011/05/naudio-audio-output-devices.html) is the first link in the NAudio FAQ and should tell you all you need to know. The quick answer though, is use WaveOut

Comment: i browsed it quickly, dosen't give a quick answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically have four options for playing audio with NAudio:

- **AsioOut** - For most things, ASIO is probably overkill. But if you need very low latency playback, this is your best bet. It requires a sound card with ASIO drivers or the program ASIO4ALL.
- **DirectSoundOut** - Uses DirectX for playback.
- **WasapiOut** - General purpose playback for Vista and Windows 7.
- **WaveOut** - General purpose playback for any version of Windows.

All of them implement IWavePlayer, so once instantiated, using them is pretty much the same for each class - just call Init() and pass in your IWaveProvider. All of them except WasapiOut can be constructed without paramaters, so all you need is:

```
waveOutDevice = new WaveOut();
```